# Security issue in iOS app build: The binary may contain the following banned API(s) _memcpy, _alloca, _gets

Tags: ios, swift, security, cocoapods

My iOS app is developed in swift. It contains some cocoa pods and other trusted third party frameworks. Build is stable and in running mode. Now when security official has done a security assessment on the app they have come up with above mentioned issue. The app was shared in installable forms and somehow they have used some tools to analyze the app(though ipa was not shared directly tool raised this issue in app ipa, tool is unknown here).

Now when I search for above mentioned API's as keywords in the whole project , I don't find its usage. Can anyone help on this , on how to trace if our code / other libraries are using these API's or not, if using , how one can rectify its usage?

Comment: Why is `memcpy` banned? It's a basic C function of the standard C library and essential for many operations. You will have a hard time finding third-party apps that don't use it. Even the C/C++/Objective-C compilers will generate calls to `memcpy`.

Comment: @Codo Did you see the underscore?

Comment: Are you sure this is relevant? At linker level, `memcpy` often becomes `_memcpy`. I think this applies to iOS as well. Or is it the main point of the inspection: use `memcpy` instead of `_memcpy`?

Comment: If the security assessment was done with [Mobile Security Framework](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF), then the error messages is likely a false positive (see https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF/issues/995). And most likely your security officiers won't be able to explain why `memcpy` is a problem as the check of the tool are not documented.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that some or one of the 3rd Party lib/s used in the project are possibly using those API's. Please do insure that the app is using the latest release of the lib/s and it may be worth while to contact the lib developers so see if they have addressed such issues in any release. To get a better perspective please go through the secure coding guidelines from Apple with respect to [Buffer Overflow / Underflow](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/BufferOverflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002577-SW1)